# Which HTTP Methods does AJAX use or support?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, http

Given HTTP supports various methods like `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE` ( and more like `PATCH`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS` etc). I am thinking which of these methods does a `AJAX` request use. Or does we have the option of saying which of these methods we want to use while making `AJAX` requests.

Comment: Maybe this [question can clarify you doubts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers), take a look.

Comment: This question should not be marked as duplicate. For novice developers, it is difficult to understand similarity between AJAX and browser supported HTTP methods. Moreover, the question here marked as original talks about form submission. AJAX has nothing to do with form submission. One can simply program AJAX without HTML form element. This was a very valid question.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax supports all of the above. It's especially easy to specify which method you want to use if you use jQuery.

Comment: Well, it's not harder with plain XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: I meant that using jQuery for ajax is easier in general than straight JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, but they do not differ at all with respect to specifying the request method.

Answer (score 1):

HTML forms (up to HTML version 4 and XHTML 1) only support `GET and POST` as HTTP request methods. A workaround for this is to tunnel other methods through POST by using a hidden form field which is read by the server and the request dispatched accordingly.

However, `GET, POST, PUT and DELETE` are supported by the implementations of XMLHttpRequest (i.e. AJAX calls) in all the major web browsers (IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera).

reference : [Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)